# Unable to automate HTML5 DragAndDrop in IE11

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

Are there any work around to make HTML5 Drag and Drop work in IE11 with Selenium Webdriver with java? I am using Selenium-Webdriver 3.4

Please find the attached for more details about the HTML. I have used the below Locator to locate the elements which works fine with Action class in chrome but not in IE11.

**Web Element Initialisation**

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, css =".work-card-description.searchable-field")
private WebElement weDragFrom;


@FindBy(how = How.CSS,css = "div.resource-schedule.resource-ui-droppable 
div.hour-line:nth-of-type(11)")
private WebElement weDragTo;
```

[Please find the Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QRV3.png)

Comment: "Does not work" is a very general term. **How** does it not work? It can't find elements? It can't click mouse button? It can't drag mouse to appropriate location?

Comment: I am using the same locator with action class for chrome which works absolutely fine . It would be helpful if i can have any another alternative method for to drag and drop in IE11 said that Action class is not working for IE

Comment: What exactly is it doing?  Is it not dragging?  Is it not dropping?  Does it drop it in the wrong place?  Are there errors that are being triggered?

Comment: It is not throwing any error nor doing nothing. r just dragging only half way and leaves it does't drop at right place.